# GestureDetector motion related to width?

Tags: flutter

I have a GestureDector wrapping a Container.

I am trying to do some logic based on where motions land relative to the total width of the GestureDetector. But I do not know the width ahead of time, so there is no way I can do this logic.

What is the proper way to go about achieving this in flutter?

Comment: If GestureDetector is not inside some scrollable widget you can use LayoutBuilder. This widget provides constraints with width & height

Comment: Can you explain that `logic`?